# Models of Unstable Theories Interpret Linear Orders

Tags: model-theory

Does $T$ having the order property simply mean that there is a formula $\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ and model $M$ of $T$ such that $\phi$ defines an infinite linear order in $M$ on some set of $n$-tuples of elements of $M$?

Is this the same as interpreting an infinite linear order in some model?

Comment: The (theory of the) random graph is unstable but doesn't interpret an infinite linear order. The point is that the "bad set" witnessing unstability **need not be definable**.

Comment: to add to @NoahSchweber's comment, I will say that it is an open conjecture whether every unstable theory with an additional property called the "no independence property" interprets a linear order. see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07949) for some progress and discussion